# HTML5 form validation out of view not getting message popup Mac Safari

Tags: html, validation, safari, field

I have a simple form with just a long list of text fields. Each of the fields is marked as required. Like so:

In the browser, if I scroll an invalid empty field out of view and then submit the form. The form will scroll to the invalid field, highlight the field's border, but the message popup which should contain the validation text 'Please fill out this field' does not display.

If however, the empty field is within view when I submit the form - then Safari does show the message bubble and text as expected.

I'm using the Safari Browser (Version 12.0.2) on the Mac.

Here is an example of a very simple form.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ho0udrw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input required="required"></br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: did you got any fix? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what's supposed to happen is the message bubble pops up, then disappears if you scroll the window. So Safari pops the the bubble and then scrolls the window to put the problem field in view, which then closes the bubble. Oops.

Here's a possible workaround: add a second submit button

```
<form>
  <input required name="foo">
  <button class="submit">submit</button>
  <button class="safari"></button>
</form>
```

hide it via css

```
.safari { display: none; }
```

and use javascript to trigger click on the hidden button after the user clicks the visible button.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.safari').click()
  }, 1);
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m3t6pnq/)